# Deduce the numbers! (Fourth edition)

Tags: logical-deduction, number-theory

The two perfect logicians $A$ and $C$ meet their colleague $B$ at an exam, and they are not aware of the fact that $B$ is a moron and a horrible mathematician.
At the exam, the examiner informs them that he has chosen two **different** integers $x$ and $y$ with $2\le x<y\le100$, such that $y$ is a multiple of $x$.

The examiner then tells the difference $d=y-x$ to the first mathematician $A$,  the ratio $r=y/x$ to the second mathematician $B$, and the sum $s=x+y$ to the third mathematician $C$ in such a way that none knows which numbers have been whispered to the others.

The three mathematicians then start this implying conversation:

- $A$: I don't know the numbers, and I know that you both know this.
- $B$: I already knew the numbers when the examiner told me their ratio.
- $A$ and $C$ simultaneously: Aha! We have just deduced the two numbers.
- $B$: Oops, damn, I am sorry! I think I made a mistake in my calculation. 
  As a matter of fact, the ratio $r$ does not allow me to deduce the two numbers.

### **Question1:** What are those two numbers $x$ and $y$??

### **Question2:** What are those two numbers $x$ and $y$, if the following conversation took place instead from the third line on??

- $C$: Aha! I have just deduced the two numbers.
- $A$:  I strongly recommend for $B$ to recalculate his ratio because he was surely wrong according to my data.

> For hints and notes, refer to the following links:
>   [Deducing Two Numbers based on their Difference and Ratio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9499/know-the-numbers-from-this-conversation)
>   [What are the numbers?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9400/what-are-the-numbers)
>   https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9525/what-are-the-numbers-third-edition

Comment: All your linked previous puzzles were found to be broken. Please stop posting these.

Comment: Make a puzzle that has less options, such as 25X25.

Comment: @xnor the solution will be added like anytime before ,  just have patience .

Comment: @Abidare001 I am not convinced you should necessarily stop posting these but as I have found errors in 2 of your final solutions after having put more effort into finding answers to your questions than I have any other questions on this site ever looking (*whew*) you need to seriously put more effort into confirming your solutions before posting.  That being said, i've not had enough time to consider this one yet.

Comment: Ok I might have been wrong to defend this.  There doesn't seems to be a correct answer here either.

Comment: ill refrain from posting these kinds of puzzles butbelieve me. those puzzles are right.

Comment: this s enugh, an answer to this puzzle will be posted tomorrow. take time to review its validity i know it s nt that easy to comprehend

Comment: why does this puzzle keep on being downvoted i think everything is disambiguated now !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Magic numbers are :

> 4,23 = **92** and **4**

first off lets note that such a coupe i,j is a representation of two numbers ij and i

Now , the first sentence in the intersection of two lists , the list of addition and division guy conditions , it is the following

```
5,12                11,6 

3,24                23,4        

2,47                4,24               

2,45                4,23               8,12               11,9               

2,33                4,17               8,9               16,5               32,3               

2,29                4,15               7,9               8,8               14,5               28,3
```

you can verify the evidence of this list by this little xls tool

[Xls file](http://www.4shared.com/file/c1INXZsRba/addsub.html)

this scripted excel sheet extracts the list of numbers which fits that the diference guy knows that summer knows that he doesnt know for sure , the second sheet shows how subtractor is sure about divisor knows that subtractor dosent know with a perfect explanation.

the final list is an intersection of those two lists.

now divisor knows the numbers which means j>33.

now both guys knows also which means the list will be truncated to :

```
2,47                4,24               

2,45                4,23               8,12               11,9
```

the list concerning summer and intersecting the upper lists is

```
2,47        3,31        4,23        6,15         8,11        12,7       16,5         24,3         32,2  

2,45        4,22        23,3
```

know divisor made a mistake which means such a couple 2,x is excluded , the only couple which appears twice in last two lists apart 2,x is 4,23

to be honest i cant go with explanation further than this.

thanks for your downvotes.

---

***second Question:***

the number is an intersection between this list

```
5,12                11,6 

3,24                23,4        

2,33                4,17               8,9               16,5               32,3               

2,29                4,15               7,9               8,8               14,5               28,3
```

and this one

```
2,47        3,31        4,23        6,15         8,11        12,7       16,5         24,3         32,2  

2,45        4,22        23,3
```

the only couple appeaering twice is 16,5

Which means numers in this case are

> **16** and **80**

Comment: 1st: Assume that 4,23 means x=23, y=92, r=y/x=4, d=y-x=69, and s=y+x=115. 2nd: Line 2 seems to read "I knew x and y (or i and j) immediately when r (or j) was told to me" this is inferred from your solution. If person A knows d=69, he immediately knows r=4 or 24.  This means that he immediately knows that person B is wrong when he says he knew x and y immediately from r as that would require r>33.  As A could not get believable information from a sentence he knows is incorrect; he could not possibly learn the numbers from B's statement.  This answer is, therefore, provably wrong again.

Comment: Please let me know if this issue is my not understanding your english or what your data represents.  The problem is clearly not that these problems are hard but either a miscommunication of the problem or (more likely) a flaw in your method of solving the problems.

Comment: "As A could not get believable information from a sentence he knows is incorrect; he could not possibly learn the numbers from B's statement. This answer is, therefore, provably wrong again" ... yes i agree , but the numbers which were in their minds , 2,45  for the subtractor and 2,47 for summer , were temporarily accepted until proven errounous by the last statement , the only choice left is  4,23 .

Comment: @kaine the answer was been edited there was something wrong at the beginning

Comment: Note that the "something wrong" being the actual ANSWER is very infuriating.  Nevertheless, this one does actually seem to work.  Good job.

Comment: i will review any other post maybe i would be wrong in the interpretation of my thoughts , language seems to make the butterfly effect :D

Comment: Abidare, the down-voting is a reaction to the weak formulation of your puzzles. You should correct and clean up the text, as you did with http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9499/deduce-the-two-numbers-from-this-conversation (which by the way should become reopened, now that it has been corrected). Then your puzzles will be up-voted again.